# How to pass values from csv into az cli deployment as parameters

Tags: powershell, azure-bicep

I don't have much experience with PowerShell and this simple issue has been driving me up the wall. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

- I have a CSV-file with IP-range values
- I wish to pass these IP values as a parameter to a Bicep template
- The parameter is of type array, see code snippets below

CSV-file:

```
IP,Comment
10.0.0.1, Comment blabla
10.0.0.52, Comment more blabla
```

I wish to pass the IP-values into a Azure Bicep template with the following parameter:

```
param ipArray array
```

The cli command is as follows:

```
az deployment group validate -g test-rg -f .\main.bicep -p ipArray=$ipRange
```

I am unable to populate `$ipRange` properly. I have tested the following and know it works:

```
az deployment group validate -g test-rg -f .\main.bicep -p ipArray="['10.0.0.1','10.0.0.52']"
```

So I need to figure out how to build my Powershell variable according to above syntax

`$ipRange = ((Get-Content .\ip_list.csv) | ConvertFrom-Csv).IP`

```
Failed to parse string as JSON:
10.0.0.1 10.0.0.52
Error detail: Extra data: line 1 column 6 (char 5)
```

Any nudge in the right direction will be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will convert the ip range as you asked for:

```
$ipRange = ((Get-Content C:\Temp\ip.csv) | ConvertFrom-Csv).IP | ConvertTo-Json
$ipRange = $ipRange.ToString() -replace '"',"'"
$ipRange
```

Comment: That was indeed a typo, thanks for pointing out and thank you for your answer I will get started on it :)

Comment: Please mark it as an answer, if you find it as useful. It may help some one else who's looking for similar solution. Thanks!